# Self-Hosted Font with Gatsby & Tailwind (PostCSS)

Tags: gatsby, postcss, tailwind-css

I was using a self-hosted font in Gatsby and that was working well. Basically I had -

- a `fonts/` folder in which all the `.woff2` files were placed, with a `fonts.css` that had all the @font-face calls (*this way because there were almost 15 @font-face calls)*
- I had configured the `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin in `gatsby-config.js` as below

```
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "fonts",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/fonts/`
      }
    },
```

I've now installed Tailwind with PostCSS as below -

- installed `tailwindcss` and `gatsby-plugin-postcss` using yarn
- configured `gatsby-config.js` as below -

```
{
     resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
     options: {
       postCssPlugins: [
         require(`tailwindcss`),
         require(`autoprefixer`)
       ],
     },
   },
```

- imported tailwind into `gatsby-browser.js` as below

```
import "tailwindcss/base.css"
import "tailwindcss/components.css"
import "tailwindcss/utilities.css"
```

Tailwind is working fine but it isn't using the font I want to use.....even though I have configured it correctly (I think) in `tailwind.config.js`

```
extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Custom Font Family Name", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the fonts you have in `./src/fonts` are not copied to `public`? You can check by navigate to the Network tab in the developer tools of your preferred browser, filter by font and see the response. It's likely that they're 404.

A quick fix would be to manually copy the fonts to `static` directory (create one if you don't have it.)

If you're doing something special with the fonts (for example, subfontting) you might be interested in adding hash to the fonts file & replace the file name in your `font.css`.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful in finding the main issue. Turns out the order of the plugin entries in `gatsby-config.js` matters a lot. By arranging `gatsby-plugin-postcss` above the `gatsby-source-filesystem` entry for fonts, it worked. Still a mystery as to why it works this way though....